# Number of possible passwords

Tags: number-theory

A password consists of four distinct digits such that their sum is 19 and such that exactly two of these digits are prime, for example 0397. The number of possibilities for the password is?

Comment: Though you could do it by hand, I would just crank up a computer to check the $10^4$ cases.

Comment: But that will give us all combinations of 4 digits from 0 to 9 with no restrictions?

Comment: @JohnChang: That's where the "computer to check" comes in. It's not necessary here though.

Comment: Yes, generate all combinations, check the sum.  If not 19, go on  to the next.  If 19, check the number of primes.  If not 2, go on.  If 2, increment counter by 1.  At end, report the value of the counter.

Comment: Ah. I misinterpreted. I thought your answer was 10^4. Lol. :) Sorry.

Comment: It seems like everyone just elaborated my answer. What is the point? The OP got the correct answer using my method before other answers appeared. It is redundant to have duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So primes here are 2, 3,5, 7.

Taking 2,3, you need 14 more to get a sum of 19. This can be done with 6,8 only.

Taking 2,5, you need 12 more to get a sum of 19. This can be done with 4,8 only.

Taking 2,7, you need 10 more to get a sum of 19. This can be done with 1,9 or 4,6 only.

Taking 3,5, you need 11 more to get a sum of 19. This cannot be done.

Taking 3,7, you need 9 more to get a sum of 19. This can be done with 1,8 or 0,9 only.

Taking 5,7, you need 7 more to get a sum of 19. This can be done 1,6 only.

That gives us 6 sets each represents $4!=24$ combinations, so there are 7*24=168 possible passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a python snippet

```
primes = [2,3,5,7]
others = [0,1,4,6,8,9]
npasswords = 0
for i in primes:
  for j in primes:
    if i < j:
      for k in others:
        l = 19-i-j-k
        if l < k and l >=0 and l not in primes:
          print("%d %d %d %d" % (i,j,k,l))
          npasswords += 24 # add !4 for all permutations
print("found %d passwords" % npasswords)
```

Here is the output

```
2 3 8 6
2 5 8 4
2 7 6 4
2 7 9 1
3 7 8 1
3 7 9 0
5 7 6 1
found 168 passwords
```

Comment: Rather a lot of these have three primes such as `2395`. One (`3565`) has the same number twice

Comment: Oh right, forgot one test, and edited code

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have 2, 3, 5, and 7 as our primes. Take 2 and 3. Now the problem reduces to finding $X$ and $Y$ in $23XY$ so that $2 + 3 + X + Y = 19$, $X \ne Y$, $X \ne 2$, $X \ne 3$, $Y \ne 2$, and $Y \ne 3$. You could do this by hand if you are systematic. Repeat the same process for 2 and 5, 2 and 7, etc. You could also write a Java program or ask for help at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm getting 168 passwords. Is this correct? :)

Comment: @JohnChang Yes.

Answer (score 0):

By hand

```
p1 p2 remaining other pairs
2  3     14         6,8
2  5     12         4,8 
2  7     10      1,9  4,6      
3  5     11          -   
3  7      9      0,9   1,8  
5  7      7         1,6
```

So $4! \times 7 = 168$ possibilities